# How to get the next frame presentation time in Vulkan

Tags: c++, winapi, vulkan

Is there a way to get an estimated (or exact) timestamp when the submitted frame will be presented on screen?

I'm interested in WSI windowed presentation as well as fullscreen on Windows and Linux.

UPD: One of the possible ways on Windows is `IDCompositionDevice::GetFrameStatistics` ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/dcomp/nf-dcomp-idcompositiondevice-getframestatistics)), which is used for DirectComposition and DirectManipulation, but I'm not sure is it applicable to Vulkan WSI presentation.

Comment: What would you do with this information?

Comment: Do you talk about time dependent update logic? What you want seems neither possible nor usefull.

Answer (score 2):

[VK_GOOGLE_display_timing](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_GOOGLE_display_timing.html) extension exposes timings of past presents, and allows to supply timing hint for a subsequent present. But the extension [is supported](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php?platform=android) only on some Androids.

[VK_EXT_display_control](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_EXT_display_control.html) provides a VSync counter and an Fence signal when Vblank starts. But it only works with a `VkDisplayKHR` type swapchain. And it has only some small [support](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php?platform=linux) on Linuxes.

The appropriate issue has been raised at [Vulkan-Docs#370](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/370). Unfortunately, it is taking its time to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the exact presentation time (which would be tricky in any case, since monitors have some internal latency). I think you can get close though: The [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkAcquireNextImageKHR) for `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` say you can pass a fence that gets signaled when the driver is done with the image, which should be close to the time it gets sent off to the display. If you're using `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` you can then use the refresh rate to work out when later images in the queue get presented.